# Count based on paired matches/mismatches in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in this format, but with many more rows:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'], 
     'col2': ['catA', 'catB', 'dogA', 'dogB', 'snakeA', 'snakeB']})
```

For each `animalA/animalB` pairing, I want to count whether `col1` is a match/mismatch for those two rows. I know I can sort them with `dftest.sort_values('col1')` to put the two rows together, but am unsure how to compare the two rows after that.

There are hundreds of values for `col2`, but only 4 values possible for `col1`, if that makes it easier.

For example, in the rows with `catA/catB`, `col1` has `A/A`, so this is a match. In the rows with `dogA/dogB`, `col1` has `B/C`, so this is a mismatch. If the letters for the two rows with `animalA/animalB` are the same, it's a match. If they differ it's a mismatch.

Desired output for this small example:

```
countMatch = 2
countMismatch = 1
```

Comment: How's your count mismatch 1 in your example?

Comment: @MohitMotwani Updated the question to be more clear! Above the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the last letter from `col2`, group by the new string and count the unique `col1`, i.e.

```
dftest['newcol'] = dftest['col2'].str[:-1]
i1 = dftest.groupby('newcol')['col1'].nunique()

print('match: ', sum(i1 == 1))
#match:  2
print('MisMatch: ', sum(i1 > 1))
#MisMatch:  1
```